# Profile attributes relationship with Data Extensions

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder, dataextensions

Recently i've working with the profile attributes. But i created 2 new Attributes but somehow a trigger process we have start having issues. The Data extension we have contains the same field as the attribute Phone Number. but i have the doubt that if the profile attributes doesn't have a relationship with the Data Extension my journey can update this information?
Until i have the knowledge the attributes only affect the Lists but if someone have other information will be helpful.

Thank you so much!

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

- Profile Attributes don’t have any relationship with Data Extensions
- It’s possible to use Profile Attributes to include [personalization in emails sent from Journey Builder](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=sf.mc_jb_personalization_in_the_journey_builder_send_email_activity.htm&language=en_US), eg. If you have a Profile Attribute called PhoneNumber in All Subscribers list, you can use the string %%PhoneNumber%% to insert it into an email
- It not possible to update Profile Attributes from Journey Builder, eg. you cannot pass a value from a Data Extension into a Profile Attribute using Journey Builder (at least not oot, without using code)
- Overall, the List model including Profile Attributes is the “outdated” model and I rarely see anyone use it anymore - instead, especially if you’re using Journey Builder, Data Extension model is much better. Read more here: https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=sf.mc_es_list_versus_data_extension.htm&language=en_US

Please clarify your use case further, so that the community can better understand what you’re trying to achieve.